# Does changing the canonical tag also transfer page authority?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, duplicate-content, search-results, rel-canonical

We have 3 pages on our website with almost similar title; actually for better ux, this is necessary to separate some part of a content. 
For example:

- page1: elevator service
- page2: check list of elevator service
- page3: elevator service form
  **with different canonical**

  In  real world, they are different concepts, but because of google result, they are same for now.
  Our pages are in google serp (in different keywords), but It seems that because they are recognized as duplicated, also are in poor position (page 3,4,...)

  Now, we want to combine them without use 301 redirect, but also with canonical tag.

  Does changing the canonical tag also transfer page credit & authority?

Comment: Will it transfer all authority and credit to the new canonical? No. Is it helpful in Google indexing the correct page? Probably. My question would be this: why combine all the pages into one, use a canonical and NOT leverage a 301? What is the benefit of keeping the three pages and the newly created single page with duplicate content?